# Restore files USB memory WD turned into windows upgrade

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I've created a windows upgrade from my WD external data disk and it has taken over all of the visible files. The WD wasn't empty and had files before I turned it into a windows upgrade.

If I check total capacity, it is larger than what the windows upgrade holds, but once i open the drive to see contents, I don't see my old files.

How can I see those old files?

Comment: They have probably been overwritten. How did you create the upgrade?

Comment: using official microsoft upgrade

Comment: If you used The Windows Media Creator it would first erase the drive, then format & copy the installer files. Some of your old data may have survived, but you'll need some kind of scavenging recovery software to see what they can find. See https://superuser.com/search?q=file+recover+format for dozens of similar accidents.

Comment: If the files were removed, one of the best tools for file recovery is [`TestDisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)